# Common way to forecast multivariate time series where components are restricted by an inequality?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

Let's say we have a multivariate time series that we would like to forecast future values of: $Z_t = (X_t, Y_t)$ where $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are real-valued time series and constrained by the inequality $X_t < Y_t$ for all $t$.

If we believe that our multivariate time series, $Z_t$, can be modeled by a VAR/VECM process (potentially nonlinear), what is the common way to impose this constraint?

Would we just want to do something in our model like attempting to forecast $X_t$ without constraint and attempting to forecast $Y_t - X_t$ with the constraint that it must be greater than $0$ so that way, when we do have constraints, they're static? Or is there a way to do this without constructing a different series to forecast?

Comment: Something like $X_t \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda_t)$ and $Y_t := X_t + D_t$ where $D_t \sim \text{Exponential}(\mu_t)$ would satisfy the inequality constraint.

Comment: Fair point and thank you! @Galen , do you feel like the more practical way to go about this is to model the smaller series ($X_t$) and the difference ($Y_t - X_t$) versus attempting to model $X_t$ and $Y_t$ in a jointly-constrained manner?